# Perl MIME::Lite bad file descriptor

Tags: perl, email, smtp, send, file-descriptor

This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite;

my $to = 'example@asd.com';
my $from = 'example@asd.com';
my $subject = 'Test Email';
my $message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
             From     => $from,
             To       => $to,
             Subject  => $subject,
             Data     => $message
             );

$msg->add( "Type" => "multipart/mixed" );        
$msg->send("smtp", "good.domain.net");
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

When i want to run the script i got the following error:

> Failed to connect to mail server: Bad file descriptor at ...\email.pl
>   line 17.

I have no idea what the problem could be. Has someone any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I corrected the code above, it is working with the proper server (it does not require authentication at all).

Comment: Step 1 of fixing perl code: `use strict;` `use warnings;`. This may not fix your problem, but at least shows a bit of willing when asking for assistance .

Comment: From the documentation, it's not clear whether the additional arguments work for an instance method. Try using the class method first to set up the username/password, then use the instance method to actually send the message.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If i fail to fix the current version, i will try out other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MIME::Lite SMTP debugging procedure

Try to narrow search for your problem.

1: Do you get SMTP greeting message when you telnet the SMTP host?
`telnet mail.domain.net 25`

1:**YES** => add debug option to MIME::Lite send (via SMTP) call.

```
$msg->send("smtp", "mail.domain.net", Debug=>1, AuthUser=>'myname@domain.com', AuthPass=>"password" );
```

Comment: I think port 25 is blocked, because i can ping the server, but the telnet command fails to connect. I will try to fix the connection (check firewall, etc.). Anyway, thanks for the advice, debug option seems to be a useful thing.

Comment: I was dumb, I tried to connect to a wrong server. -,-
I found the right server, and it works now. Cheers.